# Redux-thunk "dispatch is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have configured redux-thunk the following way

```
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from "redux";
import Provider from "react-redux/es/components/Provider";
import braintrainer from "./store/reducers/braintrainer";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';



const store = createStore(
    braintrainer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
); 



ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <BrainTrainer/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Then in one of my components I map the function onLoginClicked to dispatch the startLogin action

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onDifficultySelected: difficulty => dispatch({ difficulty, type: 'SET_DIFFICULTY' }),
    onLoginClicked : (username,password) => dispatch(() => startLogin(username,password))
});
export default withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(BrainTrainer));
```

I pass the onLoginClicked function down to my Login component and call it when the login button is clicked

```
<button type='button' className='login-btn' onClick={onLoginClicked(passWord,userName)}>
    {isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Sign up'}
</button>
```

My startLogin action creator looks like this

```
import axios from 'axios';

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';

export const login = (token) => ({
    type: 'LOGIN',
    token
});


export const startLogin = (password,username) => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.post(baseUrl+'/api/auth/login',{
            username,
            password
        }).then((data) => dispatch(login(data.data.token)))
    }
};
```

Yet when I invoke the onLoginClicked function I get this error in my startLogin action creator.

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): dispatch is not a function
```

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Picture of the error

[image]

Comment: your `startLogin()` is trying to access `dispatch` in the `.then(... dispatch...)` and it isn't actually a thing.  `dispatch` is available higher.  try `this.props.dispatch` or look into refactoring a bit

Comment: Hm. I was following the example in https://alligator.io/redux/redux-thunk/

Comment: He calls dispatch inside then() the same way I do

Comment: well theres a ton of code missing (like where is onLoginClicked called? and where is mapDispatchToProps called?)

Comment: @boris-grunwald Try to return the promise in your thunk: `return axios.post(baseUrl+'/api/auth/login' ...`.

Comment: is there not at least a line number and a reference for that error?

Comment: There is still a ton missing man stop giving us tidbits give us the full file or it's not gonna help

Comment: @Deryck Added picture of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dispatch(fn)`, the `fn` needs to be a "thunk" function - to accept `dispatch` itself as the first argument. Not an anonymous function:

> <strike>`dispatch(() => startLogin(username,password))`</strike>

But the return value from `startLogin`:

```
dispatch(startLogin(username,password))
```